# Is simple GANs works same as conditional-GANs in this scenario

Tags: deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

Conditional GANs (cGAN) are designed to generate conditional data, for example I am interested in generation of only digit '9' image from MNIST dataset by apply condition on class label). Alternatively, What if I train simple GANs on dataset, contains only images of digit 9 (suppose I have enough number of examples), will also learn the same distribution of digit 9 images.? And as a result the trained generator will generate digit 9 images.?

If yes then why we need conditional GANs.?

Answer (score 0):

The goal of conditional GANS (C-GANS) is to be able to control the features of an image that will be generated. For example, in the MNIST dataset, which contains 9 digits, training a CGAN will allow you specify which digit you want to generate, rather than relying on the randomness of the input.

If your goal is only to reproduce a specific digit (e.g. 9), then a **simple GAN**, which is trained without the targets of the images, indeed, will do the trick.

You can check some of my implementations of GANS here:
https://github.com/kochlisGit/Keras-GAN